# How to update view off model in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, .net-framework-version

I have a method in my model that finds cameras on the network. The cameras are discovered one by one, and stored in a list named List Cameras. When a new camera is added or a camera is removed, It is instantly updated in the list variable.

On the view, I have

```
         @foreach(var Item in Model.Cameras) {
            <tr>
                <td>@Item.Name</td>
                <td>@Item.IP</td>
                <td>@Item.HostName</td>
            </tr>
          }
```

to show a list of cameras. How do I tell the view to update, (without reloading the page) when a camera is discovered or removed? Is this triggered from the Model or the View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is beyond the scope of ASP.NET MVC. Once an HTTP response has been sent, you cannot modify it. However, there are a number of ways to achieve real-time functionality, such as [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events), [long polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/http-long-polling) or [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

However, since you're using .NET, the best bet would probably be SignalR. SignalR is a real-time library that lets you send "notifications" from your server to any JS (or .NET) clients. Since you haven't specified the version of ASP.NET you're using, I cannot give you one direct link, but take a look at these:

- [SignalR 2 for MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc)
- [ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0)